# Adding text to char*

Tags: c++, sql, pointers, string-concatenation

Is it possible to add text to a `char*`?

Because this code gives errors:

```
name3 = "SELECT account_id FROM players WHERE name = '" + name + "'";
```

(name3 = a char*)

Comment: See [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 16):

Your question is tagged with **C++**, so use C++. Get rid of your `char*`'s and use `std::string`:

```
std::string name = "...";

std::string name3 = "SELECT account_id FROM players WHERE name = '" + name + "'";
```

You can "add" two character arrays (char*'s) by allocating a new array large enough to hold both, and copying both strings into the new array. I think you'll agree that `std::string` is easier, but it also provides less opportunity for you to introduce subtle errors into your code making debugging and maintenance simpler down the road.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you plan on doing lots of string concatenation you should be using `std::stringstream`. Also, refrain from using inline SQL if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate the memory first, for example:

```
char* name = new char[ BUFF_SIZE ];
```

and then use `strcpy` and `strcat`, but ..  you have tag `c++`. Use `std::string`

```
std::string name3 = "SELECT account_id FROM players WHERE name = '"
                    + 
                    std::string( name ) 
                    + 
                    "'";
```

or

```
std::string name3 = "SELECT account_id FROM players WHERE name = '";
name3 += name;
name3 += "'"; // or name3.push_back( ';' );
```

**Note** if `name` is not `const char*`, but `std::string`, you don't need from explicit conversions, so refer to meagar's post

Comment: `std::string` is smarter than that. At most, you need `std::string(name)`, the other explicit declarations are just clutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) for what you're describing.

Also, if this is for a database connection you may want to consider using prepared statements.

Comment: -1 for recommending the use of the unsafe `sprintf` function.

Comment: +1 for prepared statements, -1 for `sprintf` (use `string` , streams, or at worst `snprintf` .

Comment: +1 for prepared statements. Seriously, listen to this guy. Do _not_ concatenate SQL like that, _*ever*_. At best, your program will behave in odd ways when given certain input. At worst, someone will exploit this easily-discoverable security vulnerability and do something that you'll regret.

Comment: Agreed on the prepared statements. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for security vulnerabilities regarding SQL injection. However, sprintf can be even more dangerous, if you underestimate the buffer size.